# Javascript add arrays to array object - problem pushing always the same value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, foreach

I have problem with javascript code:
I'm creating a form with dynamic adding elements and foreach read values from this form

```
<div class="product" value="1">
  <br />
  <h4>Pytania dodatkowe lecz obowiązkowe :3</h4>    
  <div class="inputbox left-label required">
    <label for="price" class="rating">price</label>
    <div class="tint-rating" id="" data-input="price0" name="price" value="5"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inputbox left-label required">
    <label for="functionality" class="rating">Funcionality</label>
    <div class="tint-rating" data-input="functionality0" name="functionality" value="5"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inputbox left-label required">
    <label for="design" class="rating">Design</label>
    <div class="tint-rating" data-input="design0" name="design" value="5"></div>
  </div>   
</div>    
<div class="product" value="2">
  <br />
  <h4>Pytania dodatkowe lecz obowiązkowe :3</h4>    
  <div class="inputbox left-label required">
    <label for="price" class="rating">price</label>
    <div class="tint-rating" id="" data-input="price1" name="price" value="6"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inputbox left-label required">
    <label for="functionality" class="rating">Funcionality</label>
    <div class="tint-rating" data-input="functionality1" name="functionality" value="3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inputbox left-label required">
    <label for="design" class="rating">Design</label>
    <div class="tint-rating" data-input="design1" name="design" value="8"></div>
  </div>    
</div>    
<div class="product" value="3">
  <br />
  <h4>Pytania dodatkowe lecz obowiązkowe :3</h4>    
  <div class="inputbox left-label required">
    <label for="price" class="rating">price</label>
    <div class="tint-rating" id="" data-input="price0" name="price" value="1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inputbox left-label required">
    <label for="functionality" class="rating">Funcionality</label>
    <div class="tint-rating" data-input="functionality1" name="functionality" value="2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inputbox left-label required">
    <label for="design" class="rating">Design</label>
    <div class="tint-rating" data-input="design1" name="design" value="3"></div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

And this is code reading values from form:

```
var arr = [], rate = {};      
products = [{}];

$.each($('.product'), function(i, product) {    
  $('.tint-rating', product).each(function() {
    var x = $(this).attr("name")
       ,y = $(this).attr("value");     
    rate[x] = y;     
  });    
  products.push({rate});    //Move this line into inside the inner .each loop
});
```

Problem is the script push to array count elements of form elements, but in all only values from last (result from example):

```
0: {}
1:
rate: {price: "1", functionality: "2", design: "3"}
__proto__: Object
2:
rate: {price: "1", functionality: "2", design: "3"}
__proto__: Object
3:
rate: {price: "1", functionality: "2", design: "3"}
__proto__: Object
length: 4
```

I need values from all elements of my form not only last, like this:

```
 0: {}
    1:
    rate: {price: "5", functionality: "5", design: "5"}
    __proto__: Object
    2:
    rate: {price: "6", functionality: "3", design: "8"}
    __proto__: Object
    3:
    rate: {price: "1", functionality: "2", design: "3"}
    __proto__: Object
    length: 4
```

If someone know what is problem with my script please help me,
Thank You very much in advance!

Comment: In `products.push({oceny});`, what is `oceny` ? shouldn't it be `rate`?

Comment: @nrgwsth, agree, code makes no sense, missing oceny!  You should also move the line products.push to inside the .each loop function.

Comment: If you want to ask an input for it's `value` `$(this).attr("value")` will not reflect any changes the user might have done after the initial rendering of the page. If you want those, use the value *property*, not the *attribute* .

Comment: Please include a sample of what you would like to see it the code was doing what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code to this:

```
    products = [];
    $.each($('.product'), function(i, product) {    
      var item = {};
      $('.tint-rating', product).each(function() {
        item[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).attr("value");
      });    
      products.push(item);
    });
```

This should give you:

```
    [{"price":5, "functionality":5, "design":5}
    ,{"price":6, "functionality":3, "design":8}
    ,{"price":1, "functionality":2, "design":3}]
```

@Dean Marketing: Thank You very much, it works!! :))